# Scrolling with keyup/keydown in autocompletion results with maxheight while mouse is hovered over the results

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

Reproducable with the official example:
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#maxheight

If you type a "c", you have more than 3 Results which makes the Result List scrollable. If you now hover over the first entry, and start scrolling with keydown the focus jumps back to the first entry when you hit the latest entry and hit Keydown once more.

How do i get rid of this behaviour?